# Humming or whistling being Kol Isha

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, women, music, kol-isha

I've heard various opinions from lay-people if a woman's whistling and/or humming a tune are considered *kol isha*, which a man shouldn't listen to, and something women should be considerate of. I looked at some contemporary *seforim* (for example Halichos Bas Yisroel) but they didn't discuss it. Are there any *halacha seforim* or known opinions of *poskim* which discuss this?

Comment: How whistling can be kol isha, playing clarinet or trumpet may be kol isha?

Comment: @kouty the seforim I saw did discuss instruments, and they're no problem. You could however differentiate between the two

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2016/05/01/kol-isha-women-humming/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from Oz V'hadar L'vusha (I am sure there are dissenting opinions elsewhere):

[image]

Here is "Mekoros 73:3" mentioned above, where he writes that he found no sources discussing the matter but reasons himself that it should be forbidden as described above:

[image]
[image]

I asked Rav Yehuda Herzl Henkin this question. He answered “kolech arev”is not applicable  to whistling,but is to humming.

Comment: I was about to quote that. Note that this was (mis)quoted by R. Moshe Dovid Lebovitz in [an article](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/223487/halachically-speaking-kol-isha-and-other-tznius-issues.html) on kol ishah.

Comment: Can you include the contents of "Mekoros 73:3"?

Comment: @Alex reminds me of a famous saying by old Ben Kenobi

Comment: @DoubleAA I *think* I can guess what you're referring to.

Comment: As I suspected there is no source for it

Comment: Thank you! I'm anticipating you finding dissenting opinions :)

Comment: @robev I asked to the other extreme of the spectrum and he held that humming is also a problem,can't say didnt try

Comment: In one of the Kol HaTorah (Gateshead) periodicals, the author of the Oz Vehadar Levusah wrote a lengthy analysis of the halachic classification of humming, specifically regarding *kol isha*. I believe it was more substantial and informative than the *mekoros* given here.